# interpretation of the statement in java

Tags: java, object, constructors

I am confused over the interpretation of the following statement

```
Fruit x= new Fruit();
```

My interpretation is that the `new` operator along with `Fruit();` creates a new object somewhere in the memory.

Now `x` is a reference variable that points toward the object created and if I write `Fruit x` , does it only mean that a reference variable is created which points no where?

Can i also say that `x` keeps the memory location of the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

`new` operator reserves space in memory for a new object of Type Fruit. Assignment `=` assigns the reference to your variable `x`.

If you were to write `Fruit y = x;`, you would only create a new reference, so both `y` and `x` would still be pointing to single location on memory.

For more in-depth knowledge, check out [this article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: thank you sir ,can i say that x keeps the memory location of the object

Comment: I believe you absolutely can! :)

Comment: @user143252 A reference contains a virtual memory address which when mapped, corresponds to an exact position in physical memory.  Not even the java virtual machine knows the physical address.  The operating system handles mapping the virtual memory address to physical memory address.  Suffice to say, it is a bit more complicated than you make it sound, but lets just say that you have everything necessary to read the contents of memory.

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubts , this site is best place for people like me .

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Fruit x = new  Fruit();` creates a new object belonging to the class Fruit and `x` stores a reference to that object.

More specifically, when the computer executes this statement, it allocates memory to hold a new object of type Fruit. It calls a constructor, which can initialize the instance variable of the object as well as perform other tasks. A reference to the new object is returned as the value of the expression "new Fruit()".

Finally, the assignment statement stores the reference in the variable x. So, x can now be used to access the new object.

Comment: please elaborate ,your answer seems to confuse me what you want to explain is already explained by @Alexus said or you want to point out something else .